# Token real synchronization from my website

Tags: synchronization, token, ethereum, solidity, ico

I like to integrate a real token synchronization (From distributer wallet account to user's wallet address the token need to transfer) in my website. My website needs to interact with the blockchain real token need to be transferred to the user's wallet address

If any have experience Real token synchronization let us know as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can create node.js API with Web3 library.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/

If you want to send tokens to user you have to send raw transaction and use contract method transfer() in rawTx data, pseudocode example:

```
    let rawTx = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
        gasLimit: '0x2fefd8',
        to: tokenAddress,
        value: '0x00',
        data: contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, tokens).encodeABI(),
        chainId: '0x01'
    };


    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')).then(
        data => {
            console.log(`Tokens transfered to ${toAddress} on ${amount} TOKENS`);
        }
    );
```

If you have already sent tokens, you can check user wallet token balance with balanceOf()

```
contract.methods.balanceOf(address)
```